# How to Delete a Cell Based if Another Cell Matches a Certain Value

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am generating an excel sheet based off existing data, that the user can then modify/confirm.

I have two columns, one being `Instructions` with the options of either `Pay` or `Do Not Pay` and another column labeled `Do Not Pay Reason` that has a drop down list of options.

If a user changes the value of `Instructions` to `Pay` then I want the `Do Not Pay Reason` cell at that row to be cleared.

I tried setting a string formula

```
cellBuilder.setStringFormula("IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(\"Pay\", M" + excelForumlaRowIndex + ,")), \"\" + ", M" + excelForumlaRowIndex + ")");
```

But that does not work, because N$ is the cell value I am both trying to change and trying to keep. I have read that VBA is the only way to conditionally delete a cell value.

I am extremely new with VBAs both within Excel and Apache POI and was hoping for some guidance on what a VBA for this situation would look like, and how to apply it using Apache POI. I would also be open to any other suggestions on how to get the functionality I am looking for without using VBAs.

Comment: Are you using VBA of Java? Consider [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73506448/edit) to either have the correct tags or mention the language you are actually using

Comment: Moving on note: First, do what you want to achieve using Excel's GUI. If that works, then you know what needs to be done using Apache POI. Apache POI can only create Excel files. It does not interact with any kind of GUI. So all what shall happen by user interaction in GUI would must be predefined in the file. And Apache POI is not able to create VBA code. So all needed VBA code would must be contained in the template Excel file already.

Comment: "then I want the "Do Not Pay Reason" cell at that row to be cleared.": Is that mandatory? If not and it would sufficient if the "Do Not Pay Reason" gets invisible in that condition, then this could be achieved without VBA using conditional formatting.